# ElasticSearch adjacent words for nested queries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

I'm using **ES 7.14/Kibana 7.10**, I have to search for adjacent words (any order), hence I'm using this query:

```
{
 "query":{
    "bool":{
        "must":[
            {
                "query_string":{
                    "query":"*antonio* *banderas*",
                    "fields":[
                        "text"
                    ],
                    "default_operator":"and",
                }
            }]
      }
  }
}
```

This works ok for a `text` plain field. Now, I have a nested field `metadata`, let's say the mapping is

```
{
    "mappings:": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I would like to search that nested field in the same way (adjacent words search), so assumed that it's is possibile to write a nested query for `query_string` in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415456/elasticsearch-query-string-nested-query) way

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "metadata.text:*antonio* *banderas*"
    }
  }
}
```

How to adapt this approach to the previous one with `default_operator=and` etc.? If I do

```
   {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "metadata.text:*antonio* *banderas*",
          "default_operator": "and"
        }
      }
    }
```

I don't get any result (but any error too).

A similar question, but related to matching adjacent words for multiple nested fields is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107109/elasticsearch-adjacent-words-for-nested-queries-over-multiple-nested-fields).

Comment: for nested field you need to use nested query , with normal queries it will be treated as flat text ie  these will not be treated as separate documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjacent word with any order should not be search with `query_string` but `wildcard` or `match` or `term` or `span_term`

There is also a mapping type `wildcard` optimised for this usage, depends on what type of queries you will need.

So for you first example :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": "*antonio*"
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": "*banderas*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

OR

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "text": "*antonio*banderas*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and for nested queries :

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Since my search field type is `text` can I apply a `wildcard` query? If not, could you provide an alternative example for `term` or `match`?

Comment: Yes you can use wildcard on `text` field, just remember that `text` field type split phrase in tokens so it's like having a bunch of terms and not a phrase, to see this in action, use POST /myindice/_analyse `{"text": "my phrase is cool"}` to see how it works under the hood

Comment: Thank you. Just a note, but significative. For some reason I ignore, it only works with `match` field and `query_string`, where the former (`match`) it's 8x the latter (!); `wildcard` and `terms` do not return any result if used in this way https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/7383a912686c56428849efe4e553758a

Comment: Yes obviously, like I said `text` type transform your text into a bunch of tokens, so match will try to match one of the token, so for example `my phrase` become tokens `my` and `phrase` and you cannot `match` with `my*phrase` since it's no in valid with the `my` token and either with `phrase` token

Comment: I have an extension of this question related matching adjacent words, but for multiple nested fields  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69107109/elasticsearch-adjacent-words-for-nested-queries-over-multiple-nested-fields