# ElasticSearch adjacent words for nested queries over multiple nested fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

To search for adjacent words for nested (or not) queries, the solution is the following (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894012/elasticsearch-adjacent-words-for-nested-queries) for the answer):

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "metadata",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "wildcard": {
                      "metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This works OK. But, supposed to have multiple nested fields in which search `*antonio* *banderas*` in the same way, let's say now we have this mapping:

```
{
    "mappings:": {
        "properties": {
            "text": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "metadata": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            },
            "other_metadata": {
                "type": "nested",
                "properties": {
                    "text": {
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I want to search the adjacent words in both nested fields `metadata` and `other_metadata` shall I use `match` or `should`?
I want to have a result that matches **at least one of the patterns metadata or other_metadata**, so I thought to use `should` and set `minimum_should_match` to the number of tokens of the query (separated by a `\s` - space char) in this way:

```
{
    "should": [{
            "nested": {
                "path": "metadata",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ignore_unmapped": true
            }
        },
        {
            "nested": {
                "path": "metadata",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ignore_unmapped": true
            }
        },
        {
            "nested": {
                "path": "other_metadata",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "other_metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ignore_unmapped": true
            }
        },
        {
            "nested": {
                "path": "other_metadata",
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "wildcard": {
                                "other_metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "ignore_unmapped": true
            }
        }
    ],
    "minimum_should_match": 2
}
```

This seems to work, but my doubt is the following: the `minimum_should_match=2` condition here will assure that at least two ones of those four conditions match, but not that those two matching conditions are **both** related to the same pattern (like `metadata` for both words `*antonio*` and `*banderas*`. If so, how to ensure that? Using `must` maybe? But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do kind of sub queries like this :

`bool => should => bool => filter/must/should`

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "path": "metadata",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "path": "metadata",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "path": "other_metadata",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "other_metadata.text": "*antonio*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "nested": {
                  "ignore_unmapped": true,
                  "path": "other_metadata",
                  "query": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must": {
                        "wildcard": {
                          "other_metadata.text": "*banderas*"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works almost perfectly, but there is a sort of "drawback": If you search like `*marq* *marquez*` you will get `gabriel garcias marquez`, apparenty due to the `marq` present in `marquez`, while I would expect no results or a result with at least both the words `marq marquez`. Is this due the trailing `*`?

Comment: `*` here is only necessary if you want to match more than `marq` like `randommarq` or `marqrandom` or `randmarqrand` etc.. if you only want `marq` then remove `*`

Comment: Okay, you are right, I think I'v got it!  Basically for some fields, let's say `text` I have an `autocomplete` custom analyzer - see here https://gist.github.com/loretoparisi/dc1cdd4dea29a83e326a81a00fae2775

I assume that having this auto completion analyzer + a `wildcard` on the same field may be "invalidate" the exact search with `* + term + *` or `term`?